# Is there an command line version of the Work Item Template editor in tfpt.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs-power-tools

Is there a way to edit TFS 2013 Work Item Templates from the command line? I'm looking for this because I currently don't have access to VS2013 in a version that will allow me to use the Tools -> Process Editor functionality. It seems like it would be part of tfpt.exe, but I'm not seeing the functionality.

Comment: Beside DaveShaw's answer, Process Editor only available for Visual Studio Professional or higher, so you may have lower version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Work Item Templates are just XML in a format known as [WITD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243932.aspx).

I only ever work on customising work items in XML these days.

The command to export is:

```
witadmin exportwitd /p:TeamProject /n:Bug /f:Bug.xml /collection:http://mytfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Edit it with your favourite XML editor then import again using:

```
witadmin importwitd /p:TeamProject /f:Bug.xml /collection:http://mytfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Run `witadmin exportwitd /?` or `witadmin importwitd /?`for further help.